# Getting a probability $> 1$ in hypothesis test

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

I have the following hypothesis question.

A soft drinks company claims that of all consumers buying their product, $82 \%$ prefer the light version of the drink. To test their claim, data were collected from $52$ consumers, with $44$ preferring the light version of the product.

$H_0$: $p-p_0 = 0.82$, $H_1$: $p \neq 0.82$.

Under the null hypothesis, $X \sim \mathrm{Bin}(52,0.82)$. The observed test statistic is $x = 44$.

I need to find the value of $P(X \leq 44)$, but I get $1.48$?

Following is my code in R:

```
  > 2*pbinom(44,52,0.82)
  [1] 1.483675
```

If I run the following, reading from the right tail why is it <1?

```
  > 2*pbinom(44,52,0.82, lower.tail = FALSE)
  [1] 0.5163253
```

And why does it work for this example taking the left tail and obtaining p value <1 :

```
  > 2*pbinom(311,500,0.65)
  [1] 0.2065312
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying that `pbinom` probability by $2$? That would give $2P(X\le 44)$, so this can be greater than $1$. Do you want a two-tailed test and want $2P(X\color{red}{>} 44)$ or something?

Comment: Because I am doing it for a two sided hypothesis test and assuming symmetry to make it simpler as it is a discrete distribution. I was told to just double it ?

Comment: The thing they are telling you to double is probably a probability of $X$ being **greater** than 44, rather than less than. Anyway, we would need to know more context probably.

Comment: My notes say less than.. no idea why. This is what it says: A soft drinks company claims that of all consumers buying their product, 65%
prefer the light version of the drink. To test their claim, data were collected from
500 consumers, with 311 preferring the light version of the product. H0 : p = p0 = 0.65 vs H1 : p 6= 0.65
(c) Under the Null hypothesis, X ∼ Bin(500, 0.65). The observed test statistic
x = 311, therefore, the p-value is
2 × P(X ≤ 311) = 0.21
obtained with,
> 2*pbinom(311,500,0.65) This is a different example but I am using the same reasoning.

Comment: EDITED my question for more context.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally submitted an edit at the same time. I'll correct that now.

Comment: Cheers, thanks.

Comment: If you just want $P(X\le 44)$, just remove the doubling. Remember that in $\texttt{R}$, `pbinom` is already calculating this probability.

Comment: why is it doubled in the example?

Comment: I've improved the formatting (I encourage you to use LaTeX), but do edit again if the content is not what you wanted.

Comment: The one from the right tail is calculating the probability of being **greater** than $44$. This probability is much smaller for the given $X$, so even doubling it, it is less than $1$. This page could be worth reading: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238427/why-the-lower-tail-f-is-used-when-mannualy-calculating-the-p-value-from-t-score.

Comment: So should I take the sum from both tails? Or double the result from the right tail?

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I am just confused how one should know which tail to use as in the example the left tail works?  > 2*pbinom(311,500,0.65)
[1] 0.2065312

Comment: You should probably know about the theory of these hypothesis tests. That way, you will know what probability you want to be calculating. Once you know what you need to calculate, you can go about figuring out how to calculate it in $\texttt{R}$. But if you are just told to double something without knowing why, you may never be sure that you are doing the right thing. The $p$-value represents the *probability of getting a "more extreme" result than observed, under the null hypothesis*. What "more extreme" is depends on the form of the hypotheses. Hopefully your notes have explained this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin by temporarily putting the formulas aside and trying to take
an intuitive view of the test of  the null hypothesis $H_0: p = p_ = 0 = 0.82$ against
the two sided alternative $H_a: p \ne 0.82,$ based on $n = 52$ observations with
$x = 44$ Successes (people who prefer the sugarless version).

**Exact binomial test:** The test begins by assuming that the observed number of successes is
$X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n = 52,\, p = 0.82).$ The figure below shows the PDF
of this distribution.

[image]

If $H_0$ is true, we expect on average  $np_0 = 52(.82) = 42.64$ successes (vertical dotted blue line).
We observed $x = 44$ Successes, slightly more than expected. The corresponding bar in the plot is shown in red. 
The question is whether the observed value $x = 44$ is enough different from the
expected value  (42 or 43) to cast doubt on the truth of the null hypothesis.

*Now we need to do some computations:* The P-value of a *right-sided* test (alternative $p > 0.82)$ is the sum of the
heights of the bars at values 44 through 52. That is $P(X \ge 44) = 0.3920;$
computation in R below. This is the probability of an event as extreme or more
extreme than what we observed, *in an upward direction.*

```
sum(dbinom(44:52, 52, .82))
## 0.3919817
```

For the P-value of a 2-sided test, we also need the probability of a result as or more extreme
*in a downward direction.* In a symmetrical situation, we would just choose the probabilities of the bars as far below the dotted blue line as $s = 44$ is above.
(But in this problem it's not exactly clear whether to use the combines heights of bars at or below 42 or
to use the combined heights at or below 41. The two probabilities would be about 0.4844 and 0.3289, respectively.)

```
pbinom(42, 52, .82)
## 0.4644076
pbinom(41, 52, .82)
## 0.328853           # See Note (b) at end
```

In such a case, some statisticians *double the
one-sided P-value* 0.3920 to get the two-sided P-value 0.7840.  Consequently, testing at the 5%
level of significance, we do not have evidence to reject $H_0$ against the two-sided
alternative because the P-value $0.7840 > 0.05.$

```
2*sum(dbinom(44:52, 52, .82))
## 0.7839634
```

**Normal approximation with continuity correction:**  An alternative method
is to use the normal approximation to the normal distribution. Let $n = 52,\, x = 44,\,$
$p_0 = 0.82.\,  \mu_0 = np_0 = 42.64,$ and $\sigma_0 = \sqrt{np_0(1-p_0)}.$
Then the test statistic is $Z_0 = (43.5 - \mu_0)/\sigma_0,$ where the use of
43.5 instead of 44 is called the 'continuity correction'. [Under the approximating
normal curve, the probability associated with $x = 44$ lies above the interval
$(43.5, 44.5).]$

Then under $H_0,$ the test
statistic is approximately standard normal. The P-value is $P(|Z| \ge Z_0) = 0.76.$
Computations in R are shown below. Even though we approximated the two-sided P-value (0.784) of the 'exact' binomial test by doubling the one-sided P-value, that result is generally regarded
as more accurate than the P-value (0.76) from the normal approximation. (Even with a continuity correction one does not expect more than two-place accuracy from a normal approximation when $n$ is below about 100.)

```
n = 52;  x = 44;  p.0 = .82; mu.0 = n*p.0;  sg.0 = sqrt(n*p.0*(1-p.0))
z = (43.5 - mu.0)/sg.0; z
## 0.3104228
p.val = 2*pnorm(-z);  p.val
## 0.7562395
```

---

*Notes:* (a) In R, `dbinom` denotes a binomial PDF and `pbinom` denotes a binomial CDF.
Also, `pnorm` denotes a normal CDF. The notation `44:52` denotes a vector of integers from 44 through 52.

(b) Even though some statisticians double the (observed) one-sided P-value to get the P-value for the two sided test, there is not universal agreement on this. I showed the 'doubling method' because you mentioned it in your question.

Here is output from `binom.test` in R:

```
binom.test(44, 52, .82, alt="two")

        Exact binomial test

data:  44 and 52
number of successes = 44, number of trials = 52, p-value = 0.7208
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.82
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.7191889 0.9311608
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.8461538
```

The P-value shown here is $P(X \ge 44 | p=.82) + P(X \le 41 | p=.82) = 0.7208$ (one of two choices mentioned above, but not used).
Of course, the conclusion is the same: there is not evidence to reject $H_0.$

```
x = c(0:41, 44:52);  sum(dbinom(x, 52, .82))
## 0.7208348
```

(c) Not all statistical software uses the continuity correction. For example, Minitab 17, under the normal approximation option, omits the continuity correction to get P-value 0.623.

Comment: Additional information on the [one-sided exact binomial test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435999/the-exact-binomial-test-formula).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.