# Binomial distribution confidence interval using a random sample?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution

I am working with the binomial distribution Bin(52, 0.82) 
I am looking to find the confidence interval for the observed test statistic of 44 successes.

I have generated a random sample of length 1000 in r using:

```
   > rbinom(1000, 52,0.82)
```

How do I find the confidence interval using only this generated sample?

Comment: Isn't your question answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3150889/getting-a-probability-1-in-hypothesis-test?

Comment: That's concerning p-values.